# Gnuplot using bash 2D array

Tags: bash, gnuplot

I would make charts with multiple labels at mins and maxs.
I have a "2D array" in bash:

```
for ((i = 0; i < 4; i++)); do
    T_min[i]=$(awk -F "," -v t="$(($t_mid - ($i * 24*60*60) - (12*60*60)))" 'BEGIN {min = 999} {if (($1 > t) && ($1 < (t + 24*60*60)) && ($2 < min)) {min = $2; pos = $1}} END {printf ("%d,%.1f", pos, min)}' $TMPFILE)
done
```

output is:

```
1553778386,12.0 1553694671,10.1 1553606887,8.6 1553522781,10.6
```

and I'd like to use it in gnuplot:

```
do for [i=0:3] {
    set label "${T_min[i]#*,}" at ${T_min[i]} center offset 0,0.7 tc rgb "#d00000"
}
```

but output is an error:

```
line 0: undefined variable: center
```

I've tried all kind of inserting "i" but none work.

Comment: gnuplot can't interact with shell directly, use `system`, for example: `a=system("echo $PATH"); print a` . As for bash arrays, I don't know what you can do; but why not redirect your awk output to a file and then use it in gnuplot?

Comment: I don't know what your awk script exactly does, but if you can explain how to get to your data and what the datastructure is, it probably also can be done within a gnuplot script. Concerning your error: a label expects coordinates `x,y`, but it looks to me that you're giving only one value, unless `${T_min[i]}` is of the structure `x,y`.

Comment: Awk looks up for mins and maxs. I know gnuplot can do it, but I need it within range of data where mins are other ranges than maxs. In words: it finds mins and maxs of temperature within 3 days. Some example of implementing this would be nice.

Comment: ${T_min[i]} is of structure x,y, usage of ${T_min[0]} works.